# Perplexing words - Edible and Eatable

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

If something is fit/okay for consumption, we use these words. While I find *edible* most commonly on the labels of anything eatable/edible, this raises the doubt whether eatable is understood by all.

My homework: I went through some [forums](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=971409). I liked an example of a fish. Fish is *edible* but I don't like fish so it's not *eatable* for me. This means anything that is fit to consume is edible but anything *not eatable* is a personal choice.

The doubt further perplexes me as I find this (note my examples in the brackets) -

> [eatable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/eatable) - fit to be consumed as food (a smartphone is not eatable). 
>   [eatable](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/eatable) - good enough to be eaten (stale food is not eatable but if I ignore the health hazards, it's *edible* right because it's not a smartphone?)

Comment: just say edible.

Answer (score 4):

Eatable is hardly ever used. As a matter of fact, I can't think of a single time that I have *ever* used that word except to tell the reader that edible is a word that will always work better.

Comment: That's true – in modern English. [Interesting Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=edible%2C+eatable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) on this one.

Comment: Nice. Well there ya go. Eatable is barely a word anymore.

Comment: no downvoting but did you really answer my question? I think this better goes as additional knowledge but in as a comment! :)

Comment: That's true, but I'm saying there is no good answer to your question because the "word" in question is so archaic as to not be a word.

Answer (score 1):

There is no semantic difference between the two words.

The suffix "-able" connotes a hard limit of possibility in either case, and will not be understood to delimit preferences.

As Jolenealaska has said, "eatable" is no longer in use, so you will only ever need knowledge of it to understand that someone writing in previous centuries is indicating that something can be eaten.

Answer (score 1):

I found one whole website on eatable flowers so "eatable" isn't dead yet. 
Its perhaps more of an emphasis be able to be eaten by itself using your mouth as against "edible" being usable for food. Cinnamon is edible but try eating a tablespoon- its not eatable due to its extreme dryness.  Its not a hard and fast definitional distinction.

eatable-flowers.com